# Why would a NSPersistentContainer lazy var getter work in production code but fail in a unit test?

Tags: swift, unit-testing, lazy-evaluation, xctest, nspersistentstore

If the following code is run normally the value of `let container` in `doSomething()`'s `guard` statement is a valid `NSPersistentContainer` object. However, when called from a `XCTestCase` class it is `nil`. Why might that be, please?

Interestingly, in both cases the value of `let container` inside the `lazy var persistentContainer` closure is a valid `NSPersistentContainer` object, so why when `return container` is run it produces a `nil` value within `func doSomething()` is mystifying.

Thank you for reading.

```
import CoreData

extension CoreDataThing {
    func doSomething () {
        guard let container = persistentContainer else { return }
        print( "something gets done here..." )
    }
}

class CoreDataThing {
    lazy var persistentContainer: NSPersistentContainer? = {
        let container = NSPersistentContainer( name: "DataModelName" )
        container.loadPersistentStores { _, error in
            if error != nil { fatalError( " Core Data error: \( error! )" ) }
        }
        return container
    }()

    required init () {}
}
```

A second question that suggests itself here is: where should the `DataModelName.xcdatamodeld` file that `NSPersistentContainer` looks for *actually live* in this context: alongside the production code; or alongside the unit test files; or a matching version in both; or somewhere else entirely?

Comment: I strongly suspect that the answer to the second question is: alongside the production code.

Comment: As to the first and main question: the "production code" in question is actually a Cocoa Touch Framework project as opposed to a common-or-garden Xcode Swift app project, and I'm beginning to suspect that this might be the problem.

Comment: I probably should've mentioned that, apologies all.